# java.lang.NullPointerException al añadir .toLowerCase()

Tags: java

Simplemente he añadido `.toLowerCase()` para que todos me pase todas las letras a minúsculas, y me aparece un error de NullPointerException. Sin esa línea va todo bien:

```
String code = game.getValues().get(Constants.VALUE_MSSTORE_URL).toLowerCase();
```

La variable code tiene tanto letras como números. No creo que sea eso porque lo he probado en algún otro ejemplo y funciona bien, debe ser alguna excepción que no recoge.

Comment: Ese error suele aparecer porque intentas aplicar `.toLowerCase()` a un valor `null`

Answer (score 3):

Lo único que se puede aconsejar es que evites el null:

```
// Se recupera el valor del mapa
String value = game.getValues().get(Constants.VALUE_MSSTORE_URL);
String code = "";

// Se comprueba que no sea nulo
if(value!=null){
    code = value.toLowerCase();
}

// Si código tiene valor
if(!code.isEmpty()){
    // Haz algo
}else{
    // Haz otra cosa
}
```

Comment: ¡Gracias! Es lo que había hecho pero esperaba que hubiese una forma de ponerlo en una línea. He estado probando y de momento no me ha dado problema.

Comment: He dejado el programa toda la noche ejecutándose y me acaba de devolver de nuevo el error. Estaba usando como condicional `!code.equals("null")`. Probaré con el tuyo a ver si funciona.

Comment: Claro, es que puede que code sea null y por tanto, al ejecutar el método equals sobre code también te lanzará una excecpción NullPointerException